# Need Help to create query for below requirement

Tags: sql

MY Table  T1

```
CID  Code   Addr    City              State
S10   10     20   bangalore        Karnataka
S20   20     35   Hyderabad        Telangana
```

My result set should be like

col 3 Addr refernce 20 is a value of colum2 Code in 2nd row and the result set should be in one row for both the rows

```
CID     Code  Addr    City          State          City       State
S10     10    20      Bangalore     Karnataka      Hyderabad  Telangana
```

Comment: That's called a self join.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (
  CID varchar(20),
  Code varchar(20),
  Addr varchar(20),
  City varchar(20),
  State varchar(20)
)

insert into @table SELECT 'S10','10','20','bangalore','Karnataka'
insert into @table SELECT 'S20','20','35','hyderabad','Telangana'

    
SELECT
  t1.CID,
  T1.Code,
  T1.Addr,
  T1.City,
  T1.State,
  t2.city,
  t2.State
FROM (SELECT Code from @table where addr in (select code from @table) group by code ) codesTable
inner join @table t1 on codesTable.Code = t1.Code
 inner join @table t2 on t1.addr = t2.Code
```

Self joins but specifying the addr column must exist as a code column

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight-forward *self-join*, for your desired results you just need:

```
select t1.*, t2.city, t2.state
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.code=t1.addr
```